# filament notifications action dispatch event - didnt work, why?

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

In my Laravel Filament project (run on docker container), I create database notifications in response to the client side in the travelController.php file
The notification is created successfully and appears in the panel in the list of notifications
However, I also added an action button to the alert that is supposed to dispatch to the event sitting in the LiveWire component
In practice, pressing the button does not cause any response
No errors at all
The code does not enter the function of the event at all

in my travelController.php

```
                  try {
                    $gender = __($driver->gender);
                    Notification::make()
                        ->title("driver {$driver->name} want to get travel num {$travel->id}")
                        ->icon('heroicon-o-chat-bubble-left-ellipsis')
                        ->iconColor('success')
                        ->body("<b style='color:green'> {$driver->group->name} </b>
                           {$driver->car_type} {$driver->car_year} 
                        <br/> {$gender} {$driver->sector} 
                        <br/> {$travel->from}-{$travel->to} {$travel->details} {$travel->price} 
                        {$travel->extension}")   
                        ->actions([
                            Action::make('confirm')
                                ->button()
                                ->dispatchTo('TravelAction', 'confirm-driver-to-travel'),
                            Action::make('cancle')
                                ->color('gray'),
                        ])
                        ->sendToDatabase($notifyUsers);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Log::info('faild to add noticatios to db');
                    Log::info($e);
                }
```

in component TravelAction.php

```
class TravelAction extends Component
{

   
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.travel-action');
    }

    #[On('confirm-driver-to-travel')]
    public function confirmDriverTravel()
    {  
        Log::info('in confirm travel action');
       
    }
}
```

When I press the confirmation button, nothing happens, the requested log is not printed, there are no errors. what could be the problem?